# Opacity not working in polygon layer with MapServer

Tags: mapserver

Doing a simple polygon layer in MapServer 8.0 and the opacity is filled in.

```
MAP
IMAGETYPE png
MAXSIZE 4000
SIZE 800 800
EXTENT -9583207 3548826 -8999182 4183713
UNITS meters
IMAGECOLOR 153 179 204
WEB
   METADATA
      "wfs_title" "mapserverdemo"
      "wfs_enable_request" "*"
      "wfs_onlineresource" "http://localhost:8080/mapserv?map=/etc/mapserver/wms.map"
      "ows_enable_request" "*"
      "wms_srs" "EPSG:3857 EPSG:4326"
      "wfs_srs" "EPSG:3857 EPSG:4326"
      "labelcache_map_edge_buffer" "-1"
      "wms_title" "OpenStreetMap"
      "wms_feature_info_mime_type" "text/plain text/html application/json"
   END
   IMAGEPATH "/ms4w/tmp/ms_tmp/"
   IMAGEURL "/ms_tmp/"
END
DEBUG 1
CONFIG "MS_ERRORFILE" "stderr"
PROJECTION
   "init=epsg:3857"
END
OUTPUTFORMAT
  NAME "png_bw"
  DRIVER "AGG/PNG"
  MIMETYPE "image/png;mode=8bit,grayscale"
  IMAGEMODE RGB
  EXTENSION "png"
  TRANSPARENT FALSE
  FORMATOPTION "PALETTE=grey.txt"
  FORMATOPTION "PALETTE_FORCE=on"
END


LAYER
    STATUS DEFAULT
    TYPE POLYGON
    NAME "h3_polygons"
    GROUP "h3"
    CONNECTIONTYPE postgis
    CONNECTION "host=host.docker.internal dbname=h3demo user=yyyy password=xxxx port=5432"
    DATA "geom from pop6 using unique fld using srid=4326"
    CLASS
      STYLE
         COLOR 255 255 255

         OPACITY 10
      END
      STYLE
         OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 255
         WIDTH 3
      END
   END
  
  PROJECTION #source
    "init=epsg:4326"
  END
END

END
```

The outlines are appearing but the polygon appears to be filled in and not showing the map underneath.

Answer (score 1):

Since the MapServer 8.0 release the OPACITY parameter must be inside a COMPOSITE object, such as:

```
LAYER
  ...
  COMPOSITE
    OPACITY 40
  END #composite
END #layer
```

Be sure to follow the MIGRATION GUIDE for all of the 8.x changes, at https://mapserver.org/MIGRATION_GUIDE.html#mapserver-7-6-to-8-0-migration

Also, before testing through WMS/WFS/OGC requests, be sure that you can first generate a valid map image using `map2img`, follow the examples at https://mapserver.org/utilities/map2img.html

Once you have a valid map image through `map2img`, then remove *all* warnings from your `GetCapabilities` response, and when you have removed all warnings, then finally you can test a `GetMap` or `GetFeature` request.